# rxjava2 observale.just(aBoolean) not

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming

Here, I am trying to create observable from boolean variable loading.

```
Observable.just(loading)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(aBoolean -> progressBar.setVisibility(loading ? View.VISIBLE :View.GONE));
```

Wherever I change the value of loading variable, I am supposed to get value in observer's onNext(),
but I am not getting the changes. 
Am I supposed to get updated value within onNext by this code? or I am trying to achieve something stupid.

Comment: i think you need to use `aBoolean` instead of `loading` inside `subscribe` and also add `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` before `subscribe`

Comment: you need to provide the complete code, i have tested it ,no issue, are your actually changing value of `aloading`

Comment: yea, I am changing the value of `loading` and I am logging it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want custom emissions from an Observable you need to use a subject instead.

```
PublishSubject<Boolean> subject = PublishSubject.create();
```

When you need to push a boolean value, you can use

```
subject.onNext(Boolean.TRUE);
```

or

```
subject.onNext(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Then you can `subscribe` to the `subject`, and with event `onNext` you call on `subject`, your `subscriber` will get the new value in its `onNext()`.

Comment: So when should we use `.just` method then?

Comment: .just(boolean) will create a stream of only one item, that will run immediately and immediately terminates. It's basically a "just" this one item.